# How to find out where the http_proxy is setting in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, proxy

When I open a new terminal and execute "export", I always can find "http_proxy=127.0.0.1:1080" there.
But after checking .bashrc in my home folder, there is nothing related with the variable "http_proxy".
So the question is, where is the environment variable http_proxy may be setting? Or how can I find out the location where "http_proxy" is setting?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check `/etc/environment`,`/etc/bashrc`.

Check what is system default shell, if you use `zsh` maybe you could find that in `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Thank you Shiri, I have found it in /etc/environment with your help.

Answer (score 1):

The grep in terminal may help, too:

```
grep --exclude-dir={proc,tmp,mnt,sys,boot,run} --exclude=\*.{md,js,html} -rnw / -e 'http_proxy'>>http_proxy.log
```

After print into current folder http_proxy.log, we can try to find where the http_proxy is set.